# How to compare OSGI bundle versions in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to compare versions such as '5.6.12' < '5.6.8' or '5.6.8-R1210' < '5.6.8-R210'.

```
RETURN '5.6.12' < '5.6.8' # true -> should be false
RETURN '5.6.8-R1210' < '5.6.8-R210' # true - should be false
```

I think the builtin comparison operators don't allow to achieve this.

How I can implement a custom comparison operator ?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what you are after, but have you looked into the Traversal API? [Java Example](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-traversal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone else will come along and tell you how this can be achieved without requiring any extra data, or using any other APIs (like my comment, I think you can achieve this using traversal (and if you are using the REST API you can wrap this in a plugin), but I have not used it so do not feel qualified to answer using it), but I do not believe that it is possible.

Failing that though, is there any reason that you have to store the canonical bundle version in isolation or could you store the canonical version and a.n.other property that stores an order value? The other property could store an integer representation of the bundle version, or some normalised string representation which would give the sort order you want lexicographically.

Do you have to store the canonical version in a single property, or could you store major, minor, micro and qualifier in separate properties. Assembling them as required, but then being able to sort numerically across the first 3 properties and lexicographically across the last?

Comment: Actually, I store the bundle version as it is, in one single property and I try to keep the solution the most basic possible. I wanted to know if there was an out of the box solution, but in the worst case, I will have to pre-process the version but the is less desirable for now.